# Linearization Theorem. Graphs from initial conditions and a DE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This is a problem I have.

I am given a DE $(\star)=(y-1)sin(y)$ and told to sketch the phase lines for $(\star)$ and identify whether they are sinks, sources, or nodes. That part I was able to do.

However, now the questions asks me to sketch solutions with initial conditions. one such condition is $y(-2)=-1$. I ask myself, the RHS does not make sense with these initial conditions. I assume I start the problem like this:

$-1=y(-2)=(-2-1)sin(-2)$

wtf is sin(-2)?? This is where I think I have the wrong idea.

If you can be the lighter fluid to my dying lighter, I would appreciate it alot. Thank you.

Comment: You mean $y'=(y-1)\sin(y)$? Then if your initial condition is $y(2)=-1$, your initial derivative will be $(-1-1)\sin(-1)$, which is just some positive number. So as you go forward in time, your solution will begin to increase. One would expect it to increase toward the equilibrium at $y=0$.

Comment: @Ian then why, I presume $y(t), y(-2)=-1$ the 2 has to play some role.

Comment: Since your equation is autonomous, the $-2$ doesn't really have a role, it just tells you at what time the process "starts". But that just changes the $t$ axis, your solution will look exactly the same.

Comment: @Ian so on the interval $-2$ to some positive number, the upward behavior will start at $-2$ and reach the equilibrium point at some positive number?

Comment: Typically, you don't reach the equilibrium in finite time; if you did, then you would have non-uniqueness of solutions, whereas you typically have uniqueness of solutions. This is true in your particular case as well. So your process will increase to zero as $t$ changes from $-2$ to $+\infty$. It will decrease to the next equilibrium below, which is $-\pi$, as from $-2$ to $-\infty$.

Comment: @Ian i do not understand. There are multiple initial conditions. so say if $y(0)=1$ you are saying that the graph will start at zero and increase to the equilibrium 1?

Comment: Er, no, you need to pay attention to what is $y$ and what is $t$. If $y(0)=1$ then you are already at an equilibrium (namely $1$) and will remain there forever. This has nothing to do with the initial value of $t$, because your equation is autonomous.

Comment: @Ian Then what is the point of having $y(0)$? why can it just be $y(t)$? I have a simpler formula then:

$y'=3y(y-1)$, equilibrium points are 0,1. i have initial conditions $y(0)=\frac{1}{2}$, $y(0)=1$, $y(0)=2$, $y(2)=-1$ I don't know what to do with the RHS

Comment: Try explicitly solving $y'=y,y(0)=1$ and $y'=y,y(2)=1$. You should find that the second solution is a horizontal translation of the first. This is my point: for an autonomous equation, changing the initial time only translates the solution. So limits at $+\infty$ and $-\infty$ do not change.

Comment: @Ian you are not making any sense man. thanks anyway.